# Find a matrix $E$ such that $EA= B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am asked to find a matrix $E$ such that $EA= B$.

I am given matrix $A$ which is $4\times 4$ and matrix $B$ $4\times4$.

Would I find $E$ the following way or is incorrect?

$$EA=B$$

$A^{-1} [EA = B]$ Multiply by $A^{-1}$ on both sides
$E = BA^{-1}$.

E = $A^{-1} B$ (Not sure if this step is correct by matrix multiplication)

So, therefore I would find matrix $E$ by finding the inverse of $A$ and then multiplying it by matrix $B$? Is that correct?

Comment: You only need to multiply on the right, not both sides, so $E=BA^{-1}$.

Comment: @Eugen: He means "both sides of the equality". Still, he is multiplying on the left, so that's the problem there.

Comment: I think that giving a solution to this post -that says nothing about the invertibility of $A$- is exactly what not to do. Doing that, we provide a very bad service to the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if matrices $$A=C$$ then $$AB=CB \tag{right multiplication}$$ and $$BA = BC \tag{left multiplication}$$
The order is important since matrix multiplication isn't commutative.
So, from $$EA=B $$$$\implies (EA)(A^{-1})=B(A^{-1}) \tag{right multiplication}$$$$ \implies E(AA^{-1}) = BA^{-1} \tag{associativity of multiplication} $$
$$\implies E = BA^{-1} \tag{as $AA^{-1}=I$ and $EI = E$}$$

Here, however we have assumed that an inverse exists ($A^{-1}$), which might not be true in general.

Comment: @LennayT If you like this answer, please upvote it. (This applies to all answers, not just mine). If you don't like some answer, downvote it. And then accept the best answer. (You do this by clicking on the grey tick mark below the upvote downvote buttons beside the answer)

Comment: Okay, thank you:) I figured it out

Answer (score 1):

yes up until the last step.  the inverse needs to be multiplied to the right of the matrix B

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& & EA &  = B \\[10pt]
\text{right: } & & (EA)A^{-1} & = BA^{-1} \\
& & E(A A^{-1}) & = BA^{-1} \\
& & E & = BA^{-1} \\[12pt]
\text{wrong: } & & A^{-1}(EA) & = A^{-1}B
\end{align}

In most cases, $A^{-1} E A$ is not equal to $E$.

Comment: What you wrote as wrong, isn't really wrong. It's equally valid but of no use. So, maybe, change that "wrong" to "left" since you already pointed out the error later.